# laravel existing application Laravel.yml to codepipeline

Tags: laravel, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codecommit, aws-pipeline

I have a laravel application in local development added to codecommit. I have added AWS Beanstalk to run this application to run,
everything works perfectly fine,

but to connect with the database and other dependencies I don't know how to add the laravel.yml to the directory,

Please help me find this. Any documentation or tutorial on this?
thanks in advance,

Comment: can't you use .env file to connect with db?

Comment: But what about the dependencies and others.how can i run those. or the migrations